# Beginner c# task error

Tags: c#, string, loops, for-loop, if-statement

so i am creating a program that will take in a string and output it as each character used and how many of that character there is in a row. For example "aaarrrgggghhhh" would output: a3r3g4h4. My current program has a bug where it wont output the last character, could anyone help me spot the error, thanks!

```
public static void Main()
{
    int count = 1;
    Console.Write(" Input a string : ");
    string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] == str1[i+1] )
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToString(str1[i]) + count);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What does `-1` do?

Comment: Also, https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#groupadjacent may be worth considering if you want a LINQ style approach.

Comment: So the problem is that the _last_ element is not being displayed and your loop goes to `.Length - 1`.  Fixing that you might see a _new_ issue.  Maybe the approach you have taken now isn't ideal.  What other combinations of loops, variables and if statements would get you to the desired output?

Comment: This might (will) help you in the future: [VS Debugging Tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Comment: Debug it. And you will realise that while it is correct to stop in the character previous to the last one, you are not taking into account when the [i+1] character is the last on the string, so that you can print what you have for the last.

Comment: In your next approach to this problem, you may want to consider using `.GroupBy()` :) Good luck to you though!

Comment: What response do you expect for the input of `AABBCCAA`? Given your 'in a row' requirement, I assume `A2B2C2A2`? Is that correct? *If* it is correct, your accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Console.Write("Input a string: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return;

        var currentChar = input[0];
        var occurrence = 1;
        var result = string.Empty;

        for (var index = 1; index < input.Length; index++)
        {
            if (input[index] != currentChar)
            {
                result += $"{currentChar}{occurrence}";
                occurrence = 0;
                currentChar = input[index];
            }

            occurrence++;
        }

        result += $"{currentChar}{occurrence}";

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: those who are downvoting bcoz of extra memory , it's not utiizing that much memory. i agree it could hv been better ,but it's not at all a bad approach.

Comment: If I input "abcabcabc" I get a1b1c1a1b1c1a1b1c1. Not what the OP was looking for. Answer by @Sumit raj produced a3b3c3.

Answer (score -2):

```
string s = "aaarrrgggghhhh";
            int[] arr = new int[124];
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[(int)s[i]]++;
            }
            string output="";
            for (int i = 65; i < 124; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] > 0)
                {
                    char c = (char)(i);
                    output = output + c.ToString() + arr[i].ToString();
                }

            }
```

Let me know if you need explanation.
Explanation:
ascii value {a-z, A-Z} ranges between 64-123. So whenever a character is found i am increasing the valur of arr[(int)character)].
Lastly i am counting how many characters were there using index.

Comment: Explanation are always needed. Either the code is self explanatory and you should give a quick intro of what where the key point or you should had additional information to give the code any value

Comment: what is the value of 'c' in this case??

Comment: sorry i missed aline ...c is "char c = (char)(i);"

Comment: Very clever. It took me a while to figure out `arr[(int)s[i]]++;`. I come from vb.net and I am not used to doing so much in one line. BTW, I get the correct answer form "abcabcabc"  a3b3c3 but the other answer doesn't give correct result.